# angularjs routing problems (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs  (3 days) and the project is simple, (i removed the login logic).

login page that sends you to the dashboard.

the dashboard contains 2 views: sidebar and main.

I'm using ui-router and i have problem with views and states.

[plunker link](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0CZG5NGYKEqVp49r?open=lib%2Fscript.js) :

for some reason , even the login page dosen't work anymore. it used to work and sends me to the dashboard with an empty view ( my views are not empty)

Comment: Add 'ui.router' dependency in app module initialization. "loginsrv.js: var app = angular.module('app.services', ['ui.router']);"

Comment: ui-router is already in the app module. added to the server but nothing changed @lzagkaretos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two issues here.

First of, you need to add reference to your scripts in the index.html page

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="login/login.js"></script>
<script src="main/dashboard/dash.js"></script>
<script src="main/dashboard/left/assets.js"></script>
<script src="main/main.js"></script>
<script src="services/loginsrv.js"></script>
```

Secondly, the preview version of the new plunker didn't work with this fix..but the old did..

Here's a working sample

https://plnkr.co/edit/HQkPhKgN6CkAVE99JSk0?p=preview

Comment: one more thing. what if my app is big with +100 js files. is there an alternative of referencing all js file in index.html ? i've seen some projects without any ref. isn't that the role of my app.js too ? I did ref everything in there.

Comment: @AmineDa. You should use a bundler for your app which will compress all the files into one. Take a look at webpack or gulp